# Django can't find me .env variables? decouple.UndefinedValueError: ENVIORNMENT not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value

Tags: python, django, python-decouple

I am very new to Django and trying to configure python-decouple to use .env variables. I am getting DB_PASSWORD not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value. when trying to run the server. The .env file is located in the root directory. Here is my code:

```
raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: ENVIORNMENT not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

settings.py

```
from decouple import config
from secrets_manager import get_secret

environment = config("ENVIRONMENT")
SECRET_KEY = get_secret(environment).get("SECRET_KEY")
DEBUG = config("DEBUG", default=False, cast=bool)

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": config("DB_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": config("DATABASE_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT", cast=int),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
        },
    }
}
```

.env

```
SECRET_KEY='nvyj6_-&m@lg87$%l3@@#+r046ioem^18+ql*)t)'
DEBUG=True
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
DATABASE_NAME=blogs
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

`Django==3.1.4 python-decouple==3.3`

Comment: ENVIORNMENT is the env var not found

Comment: Thanks. Please can you explain bit more what should I do?

Comment: You haven't specify any vue for `DB_PASSWORD`

Comment: ENVIORNMENT is spelled incorrectly, may just be a spelling mistake as ENVIRONMENT is the correct spelling? Or add ENVIORNMENT to your .env file

Comment: I fixed the spell but getting same error.

Comment: @Ahtisham I have empty DB_PASSWORD

Answer (score 2):

You are using `config('ENVIRONMENT')` in your code, without a corresponding `ENVIRONMENT` setting in your `.env` file. Make sure:

- your `.env` file is at the root directory of your project.
- you spell `ENVIRONMENT` consistently in your `.env` file and in your `settings.py` file wherever you use it.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff for replying to me. I updated my question and updated the settings.py code.

Comment: It looks like you're missing an ENVIRONMENT setting in your .env file. I also don't know what `secrets_manager` is. Is it a common package? Where can I find it?

Comment: Please can you explain how can add this missed ENVIRONMENT setting in my .env file.

Comment: You'll need to explain what the `secrets_manager` is first. The `ENVIRONMENT` setting is used by `get_secret(environment)`, and I need to know what that does before I can advise you.